# ServiceStack Text - Serialize to JSON with CamelCase on a Dynamic variable

Tags: ormlite-servicestack, servicestack-text

```
var results = await db.SelectAsync<dynamic>(q);
```

If I do `ToJson()` on the results, the names stay in PascalCase and not in CamelCase even if I use `ToCamelCase()`

```
var results = await db.SelectAsync<MyType>(q);
var results = await db.SelectAsync(q);
```

Both the above work just fine, but I cannot use since it will retrieve all the fields from `MyType` and not the ones I selected through the expression inside `q`

I believe it has to do something with the dynamic type

`JSON.NET` and `JIL` both work fine on the 1st scenario :(

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behaviour, the dynamic Type is populated from the results of the returned DataSet whose fields were in Pascal Case.

You can get the behaviour you want by creating a POCO with just the fields you want selected and serialising that, e.g:

```
var results = db.Select<SubPoco>(q);
```

Comment: Yes, I was about use a custom POCO for this as described in the ReadMe. But still the question remains  why it works in JSON.NET and Jil but not here. Any thoughts ?

Comment: @Dev answered in the first sentence.